# Javascript: Replace Pipe with Commas in a packet

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have string for example like this:

```
$K,86107,2,2,04,77.232323,86.330234,00000000000000,V,0,10,,,0,0,410,04,1e29,a16d,7000,0,1537|0|0|4762|0|0,1,0,,,,*22
```

If I use : `str.replace('|',",")` 
it only replaces the first pipe with comma.

If I use : `str.replace(/|/g,",")` the resulting string is:

```
,$,K,,,8,6,1,0,7,,,2,,,2,,,0,4,,,7,7,.,2,3,2,3,2,3,,,8,6,.,3,3,0,2,3,4,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,V,,,0,,,1,0,,,,,,,0,,,0,,,4,1,0,,,0,4,,,1,e,2,9,,,a,1,6,d,,,7,0,0,0,,,0,,,1,5,3,7,|,0,|,0,|,4,7,6,2,|,0,|,0,,,1,,,0,,,,,,,,,*,
```

What I want is:

```
$K,86107,2,2,04,77.232323,86.330234,00000000000000,V,0,10,,,0,0,410,04,1e29,a16d,7000,0,1537,0,0,4762,0,0,1,0,,,,*22
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `|` use `str.replace(/\|/g, ",");`

Answer (score 1):

As joyBlanks said, you can use a greedy regular expression to do a full replace.  You can also use `split()` and `join()`...

```
str = str.split("|").join(",");
```

`split()` splits the string into an array, with the given delimiter, and then `join()` joins the array elements with the given delimiter, returning a string.

I'd say use the regular expression, but it's worth knowing this method too.